# What is the difference between request() and submit() in Helidon's WebClientRequestBuilder?

Tags: helidon, helidon-webclient, helidon-httpclient

Helidon's `WebClientRequestBuilder` has two similar APIs: [`request()`](https://helidon.io/docs/v2/apidocs/io.helidon.webclient/io/helidon/webclient/WebClientRequestBuilder.html#request()) and [`submit()`](https://helidon.io/docs/v2/apidocs/io.helidon.webclient/io/helidon/webclient/WebClientRequestBuilder.html#submit()).  Both APIs return `Single<WebClientResponse>`.

`request()`'s Javadoc says...

> Performs prepared request without expecting to receive any specific
> type. Response is not converted and returned CompletionStage is
> notified.

`submit()`'s Javadoc says...

> Performs prepared request. When response is received, it is not
> converted to any other specific type and returned CompletionStage is
> notified.

What is the difference between the two APIs?  Is it simply that `request()` adds a wildcard `Accept` header and `submit()` does not?

Answer (score 1):

The `request` methods do not send any payload, they are short-hands that can be used to get the response entity as a specific type.

The `submit` methods can send payload and always return a response future.

```java
// do a GET request and consume the response entity as a String

client.get()
      .submit()
      .thenAccept(response -> response.content()
                                      .as(String.class)
                                      .thenAccept(System.out::println));

client.get()
      .request(String.class)
      .thenAccept(System.out::println);
```

Both `request()` and `submit()` are effectively the same:

- `request()` does not have a response entity type to work with and returns a response future instead.
- `submit()` does not have payload to send and returns a response future like its other variants.

Answer (score 0):

`WebClientRequestBuilderImpl` has the following source code.  Both APIs do the same thing.

```
@Override
public Single<WebClientResponse> request() {
    return Contexts.runInContext(context, () -> invoke(Single.empty()));
}

@Override
public Single<WebClientResponse> submit() {
    return request();
}
```